# Google Colab session timeout

Tags: google-colaboratory

In the [FAQs](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html) it is mentioned that

> Virtual machines are recycled when idle for a while, and have a maximum lifetime enforced by the system.

Are the maximum lifetime and idle times fixed or variable? Is there any way to predict them?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's 90 minutes if you close the browser. 12 hours if you keep the browser open. Additionally, if you close your browser with a code cell is running, if that same cell has not finished, when you reopen the browser it will still be running (the current executing cell keeps running even after browser is closed)

Comment: What if it is open and I am working on it continuously, like loop(change params, then execute for, say, 2-3 hours, check results)? Will the session die after 12 hours in this case also?

Comment: The reality is 18 minutes is when it disconnected when I actually observed it, as opposed to reading google's documentation. The file I uploaded was still there. Sometimes the file disappears and I have to re-upload it. I'll have to go observe what that timeout is.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson : If you mount your drive and upload to it your data will not disappear, if it's in a file like `csv, image, video, etc`. And it's quite easy with `from google.colab import drive; drive.mount('/content/gdrive')`

Comment: I don't think the 12 hour figure is accurate anymore. I left mine open to train without any interaction and it closed the session after approximately 3 hours.

Answer (score 74):

PROBLEM:
I have to training my model for hours but the google colab keeps disconnecting after 30 mins automatically if I do not click frequently, leading to loss of all data.

SOLUTION:

Steps:

1. Open the inspector view by typing `Ctrl+ Shift + i` and then clicking on console tab at top.
2. Paste the below code snippet at bottom of console and hit enter

```js
function ClickConnect(){
console.log("Working"); 
document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click();
}
setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

3. Believe me, that's all folks.
   Above code would keep on clicking the page and prevent it from disconnecting.

Below is the image showing console view of above steps:-

[image]

[image]

Alternatively you can also try below snippet:

```js
interval = setInterval(function() { 
    console.log("working")
    var selector = "#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button"
    document.querySelector(selector).shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click()
    setTimeout(function() {
            document.querySelector(selector).shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click()
    }, 1000)
}, 60*1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It is working for me. Nice!  Now I dont have to keep uploading my datafiles many times a day.

Comment: Hi @Ashish
I am getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at ClickConnect (<anonymous>:3:55)`.
Can you please help?

Comment: The element `"colab-toolbar-button#connect"` doesn't seem to exist anymore so I doubt this will still work.

Comment: As of 8/2020, change to:  
document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click();

Comment: For me, after some time into training, I only get session banner and no 'close' button at the bottom of it - i.e. I have to click outside the banner (Greyed-out portion), anywhere and not on a specific button. How shall I automate this? Edit: The above codes run without error but don't do anything.

Comment: @KaiWang this solution should work for Windows 10 users as well

Comment: I am getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')
    at ClickConnect (<anonymous>:7:66)`

Answer (score 27):

Improving on the [@Ashish Anand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5124802/ashish-anand)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59226569):

Use this code when you want to start:

```js
function ClickConnect(){
console.log("Working"); 
document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click();
}
var clicker = setInterval(ClickConnect,60000);
```

And the following code when you need to stop:

```js
clearInterval(clicker);
```

Comment: the timer will also be cleared if you just close the tab in case anyone thinks u have to run the clearInterval function every time

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear code.After I type and hide enter get undefined in the below line .. after a short time give the word working .. after a while the working pressceed with count number ... 1 then 2 and so increasing

Answer (score 4):

Another way to overcome the session timeout is to run an autoclick script in python (especially if you intend not to use your computer while running your code in colab)

Here is the code : (Be sure to pip install pynput before)

```
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode


delay = 20 #this is the delay of the autoclick (20 seconds here)
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='s')
exit_key = KeyCode(char='e')


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)


mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()


def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == exit_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Run this script on a commandline window, and then press the key "s" to start autoclicking and "e" for exit, than leave the mouse pointer on a code cell (normally it will click after a certain delay).

Comment: I get a DisplayNameError when I try to run that code in Google Colab, after I installed pynput-1.6.8.
The error is in line 2: `from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller` and it says: `DisplayNameError: Bad display name ""`
Did it anyone get it working inside Google Colab?

Comment: try to run it outside of google colab, like in spyder or even in a prompt command

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to have a sleep interval in a loop for the time you want to go out and want the session to continue.

Example:

```
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(4000) // 4000 seconds is roughly 66 minutes.
```