# Google Colab session timeout on upload

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm doing a script, where it takes in some csv and xlsx files, and one of them is around 900 MB. This takes time to upload, which means I get a session timeout. I have tried the answers in [Google Colab session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057011/google-colab-session-timeout) - also altered versions of this, but after 1-1,5 hours, it times out.

Any ideas on how to overcome this? Pynput is not an option since it's a virtual environment.

Comment: keep the browser open is the only way i think

Comment: So for around 1,5 hours just keep looking and randomly clicking in colab? I hope for another solution.

Right now I'm trying out `from google.colab import files;upload = files.upload()` so that it is a running script, instead of drag'n'drop to the folder view.