# Google Colab Pro timeout

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have trained and validated my model in Colab Pro, but when it comes to testing and print the confusion report, my Colab instance disconnects.

I have tried the solutions provided in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057011/google-colab-session-timeout) without success. How can I prevent my Colab Pro session from disconnecting?

Comment: Hi @pa1912 what can you add about the things you tried - what didn't work / what happended differently to what you were expecting ?

Comment: I was expecting a classification report. The training and validation happens quickly but when it comes to testing it times out after 5 hours

Comment: @MrR What type of information do you need? My dataset or my model or the output.

Comment: How about one of the 30+ answers to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113226/how-to-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting?

Comment: my questions where about getting you to provide sufficient information for someone else to try and reproduce your problem ... for instance is it just this model or all models, etc.