# Run time connection loss while trainig VGG 16 model on Google Collaboratory

Tags: tensorflow, runtime-error, google-colaboratory, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I'm Training the VGG16 model in colab while running it some time disconnects and reconnect again and sometimes while reaching 20, 21/35 epochs all connection loss and when I reconnect drive mounting restart due to this I lost all outputs, so I have to re-run all code. how can this problem be solved?
Even I'm using only 3000 images dataset for this which is divided into valid, train and test dataset

the code which I Run is

```
vgg16_model = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
vgg16_model.summary()

model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]:
    model.add(layer)
    

for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
   

model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

    
    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    

model.fit(x=train_batches,
          steps_per_epoch=len(train_batches),
          validation_data=valid_batches,
          validation_steps=len(valid_batches),
          epochs=35,
          verbose=2
)
```

Comment: are you loading all images at once?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute sample code using `VGG16` without any issues. Please refer working code as shown below

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import vgg16
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

train_dir  = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dogs_Vs_Cats/train'
valid_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dogs_Vs_Cats/test'

img_width, img_height = 224, 224
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

batch_size = 32

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. /255,
    horizontal_flip = True)

valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. /255)

train_batches = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'binary')

valid_batches = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    valid_dir,
    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
    class_mode = 'binary')


vgg16_model = vgg16.VGG16()

model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]:
    model.add(layer)
    
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
   
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()


model.compile(optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


model.fit(
        train_batches,
        steps_per_epoch = 10,
        epochs = 2,
        validation_data = valid_batches,
        verbose = 1,
        validation_steps = 32)
```

Output:

```
Drive already mounted at /content/drive; to attempt to forcibly remount, call drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True).
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 1018 images belonging to 2 classes.

Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 4097      
=================================================================
Total params: 134,264,641
Trainable params: 4,097
Non-trainable params: 134,260,544
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/2
10/10 [==============================] - 503s 54s/step - loss: 0.6935 - accuracy: 0.4292 - val_loss: 0.6861 - val_accuracy: 0.4912
Epoch 2/2
10/10 [==============================] - 506s 55s/step - loss: 0.6856 - accuracy: 0.4669 - val_loss: 0.6748 - val_accuracy: 0.4912
```

**Note*: To debug your code try with `5` epoch first.*

If you are facing session timeout, you can refer solutions discussed in [Google Colab session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057011/google-colab-session-timeout).