# is it possible to connect google colab pro for more than 24 hours?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am running a language model on google colab pro, and it is automatically disconnecting in less than 24 hours.
is there any chance i can use colab for more than 24 hours?
please help.
thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Colab session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057011/google-colab-session-timeout)

Comment: I don't think you can. [See here](https://colab.research.google.com/signup). " With Colab Pro your notebooks can stay connected for up to 24 hours, and idle timeouts are relatively lenient. Durations are not guaranteed, though, and idle timeouts may sometimes vary."